# Can I open arbitrary data (in memory, not in a file) in another application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-management

I'm writing a macOS application that can create its own data in the format of a common filetype (like html or csv). The idea is that it creates this data and then lets a standard system app (like Firefox or Numbers) open it.

Currently, my app saves it to a temporary directory and calls `NSWorkspace.default.open(temporaryUrl)`. I don't like this approach because it takes up unnecessary drive space while the temporary file is open, and exposes potentially-sensitive information to all other user processes. **Is there a way for me to just open the data in memory instead of opening a URL?**

I'm hoping for a call like this: `NSWorkspace.default.open(data: generatedData, type: "some.uti")`. I'd even be OK with manually specifying the app bundle identifier if need be. Just so long as I don't gunk up the drive.

Comment: You'd have to look at the apps you're interested in, and see what they support.  AFAIK, Firefox doesn't support loading data from memory -- only files or network connections.  What would the URL bar show?

Comment: You could make a gigantic `data://` URI, if you only wanted to support web browsers.  It wouldn't be very efficient, and every browser has a different max length (and some are not very big).  When the browser couldn't handle some format, it'd just save it to disk, anyway.

Comment: I was hoping that, perhaps, the OS could use such a call to tell the app "hey here's a file to open" and give it some sort of path that, when read, actually reads from memory and isn't stored on-disk. Similar to `/dev`, y'know?